# Spring Statemachine internal transition action after join is not invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

I am trying to configure a state machine with a `fork` and `join`. After joining, I would like to invoke an action on the joining state using an internal transition. The problem is that the action configured for the `withInternal()` is not triggered. I have tried the `.guard(context -> true)` hack and I have also played with `.timer()` and `.timerOnce()`, but it didn't work either.

Here is states the configuration:

```java
private void configureStates(StateMachineBuilder.Builder<String, String> builder) throws Exception {
        builder.configureStates()
                .withStates()
                .initial("A")

                .fork("B")
                .join("C")

                .state("A")
                .state("B_")
                .state("C")
                .state("D")
                .state("E")
                .and()

                .withStates()
                .parent("B_")
                .initial("B1")
                .end("C1")
                .and()

                .withStates()
                .parent("B_")
                .initial("B2")
                .end("C2")
                .and()

                .withStates()
                .parent("B_")
                .initial("B3")
                .end("C3")

                .end("E");
    }
```

Transitions configuration:

```java
private void configureTransitions(StateMachineBuilder.Builder<String, String> builder) throws Exception {
        builder.configureTransitions()
                .withExternal()
                .source("A")
                .target("B")
                .event("E0")
                .action(context -> log.info("From A to B"))
                .and()

                .withInternal()
                .source("B")
                .guard(stateContext -> true)
                .action(context -> log.info("At B"))
                .timerOnce(50)
                .and()

                .withFork()
                .source("B")
                .target("B_")
                .and()

                .withExternal()
                .source("B1")
                .target("C1")
                .event("E1")
                .and()

                .withExternal()
                .source("B2")
                .target("C2")
                .event("E2")
                .and()

                .withExternal()
                .source("B3")
                .target("C3")
                .and()

                .withExternal()
                .source("C3")
                .target("A")
                .event("E3")
                .and()

                .withJoin()
                .source("B_")
                .target("C")
                .and()

                .withInternal()
                .source("C")
                .guard(context -> true)
                .action(context -> log.info("At C"))
                .timerOnce(50)
                .state("C")
                .and()

                .withExternal()
                .source("C")
                .target("D")
                .action(context -> log.info("At D"))
                .and()

                .withInternal()
                .source("D")
                .guard(stateContext -> true)
                .action(stateContext -> log.info("At internal D"))
                .timer(10)
                .and()

                .withExternal()
                .source("D")
                .event("E4")
                .target("E");
    }
```

I have also added a listener to the state machine:

```java
private StateMachineListener<String, String> listener() {
        return new StateMachineListenerAdapter<String, String>() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(State<String, String> from, State<String, String> to) {
                log.info("State transited from [{}] to [{}]",
                        from == null ? null : from.getId(),
                        to == null ? null : to.getId());
            }
        };
    }
```

And the final configuration is:

```java
private StateMachine<String, String> buildMachine() throws Exception {
        StateMachineBuilder.Builder<String, String> builder = StateMachineBuilder.builder();

        builder.configureConfiguration()
                .withConfiguration()
                .listener(listener())
                .autoStartup(true);

        configureStates(builder);

        configureTransitions(builder);

        return builder.build();
    }
```

The problem is that none of the internal transition actions get invoked.

I have created a small test for the given configuration:

```java
@Test
    public void testForkJoin() throws Exception {
        StateMachine<String, String> machine = buildMachine();

        StateMachineTestPlan<String, String> plan = StateMachineTestPlanBuilder.<String, String>builder()
                .defaultAwaitTime(3)
                .stateMachine(machine)

                .step()
                .expectStates("A")
                .and()

                .step()
                .sendEvent("E0")
                .expectStates("B_", "B1", "B2", "C3")
                .and()

                .step()
                .sendEvent("E1")
                .expectStates("B_", "C1", "B2", "C3")
                .and()

                .step()
                .sendEvent("E3")
                .expectState("A")
                .and()

                .step()
                .sendEvent("E0")
                .expectStates("B_", "B1", "B2", "C3")
                .and()

                .step()
                .sendEvent("E1")
                .expectStates("B_", "C1", "B2", "C3")
                .and()

                .step()
                .sendEvent("E2")
                .expectStates("D")
                .and()

                .step()
                .sendEvent("E4")
                .expectState("E")
                .and()

                .build();

        plan.test();
    }
```

As a workaround, I have added several external transitions (from `C` to `D`), but the truth is I would like to omit state `D` and transit directly to `E` by executing the existing actions as an internal transition action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to omit state D and transit directly to E by executing
> the existing actions as an internal transition action.

**Short answer:** You can't.

Fork/Join pseudo states should not introduce behavior specification (e.g. Action). Fork/Join are used only to model parallel operations (fork) and synchronization (join) in the SM (transient pseudo states).

The Spring State Machine implementation follows the [UML specification](http://file:///home/hovanessyan/Downloads/formal-17-12-05.pdf) and because of that actions associated with fork/join are not executed.

Actions are associated either with particular transition or state.

#### Actions associated with transitions:

When doing a JOIN you may have N (>=2) sources (J1E, J2E - final stages of that other region), so it's possible to define different actions when transitioning from J1E to JOIN stage (action=A1) and from J2E to JOIN Stage (action=A2).

#### Actions associated with state:

If you have a common action that needs to be performed after the parallel operations are synchronized, you can define it as part of the next transition (e.g. I believe in your SM case that's when transitioning from C to D).